# Moments of the integral of the exponential of Brownian motion/Normal random variable

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, wienerprocess

I'm studying arithmetic Asian options and there is integral of the following form: $$X_T=\int_0^T e^{\sigma W_t+\left(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t}dt,$$

where $W_t$ is a Brownian motion/Wiener process.

Is it possible to calculate momnets of this integral, i.e. $E[X_T^k]$?

Clearly, $$E[X_T]=E\left[\int_0^T e^{\sigma W_t+\left(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t}dt\right]=\int_0^T E\left[e^{\sigma W_t+\left(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t}\right]dt=\int_0^T e^{rt}dt=\frac{e^{rT}-1}{r}$$

What about other moments?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the formulas of
[Baxter and Brummelhuis (2011)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.1996). They provide moment formulas for the time integral of geometric brownian motion X_t, using [divided differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences).

The full derivation is in the paper, but the formula is
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X_T^m\right] = T^m m! \exp [Tb_0, Tb_1, \ldots, Tb_m]
$$
where $b_k = kr +\frac{\sigma^2}{2}k(k-1)$, and the divided difference $f[a_0, \ldots, a_k]$ is defined recursively as
$$
f[a_0, \ldots, a_k] = \frac{f[a_1, \ldots, a_{k}]-f[a_0, \ldots, a_{k-1}]}{a_k-a_0}, \quad f[a,b] = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.
$$

You might also be interested in the paper by [Levy (2018)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042718301730), which further discusses the divided difference approach.